# How to determine if a soft link's target is a directory or a file?

Tags: files, ls, symlink, stat

Given the `ll` command outputs as follows

```
#> ll
lrwxrwxrwx ...
```

How to determine if a soft link's target is a directory or a file from "lrwxrwxrwx"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-F` parameter to ls to get:

```
   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

i.e.:

```
# ln -s videos Videos
# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 guido guido    6 Jan 23 14:11 videos -> Videos
# ls -lF
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 guido guido    6 Jan 23 14:11 videos -> Videos/
```

Anyway, I'd suggest you create symlinks to directories like this:

```
# ln -s Videos/ videos
```

in this case, you get the trailing slash even without the classify option.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `ll`, which I assume is a shell alias for `ls -l`, does not contain this information in the mode/permissions of the symlink. On Linux ([symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html)):

> ```
>    The  permissions  of  a  symbolic link are irrelevant; the ownership is
>    ignored when following the link, but is checked when removal or  renam-
>    ing  of  the  link is requested and the link is in a directory with the
>    sticky bit (S_ISVTX) set.
> ```

In addition to `ls` suggested elsewhere, there are some methods which are less verbose, and lend themselves to scripting.

`file` supports `-L` which causes it to follow (dereference) symlinks:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/xzcat
/usr/local/bin/xzcat: symbolic link to `xz'

$ file -L /usr/local/bin/xzcat
/usr/local/bin/xzcat: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, [...]

$ file  /var/adm
/var/adm: symbolic link to `log'

$ file -L /var/adm   
/var/adm: directory
```

The `-L` option is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/file.html) but should work on any contemporary Linux and *BSD. It will follow multiple symlinks (which `ls` does not). For more robust use it also supports various output formats, e.g. `file -L -b --mime-type /var/adm`, and `-0` for zero-delimited filenames.

GNU `stat`is even easier:

```
$ stat -c %F /var/adm
symbolic link

$ stat -L -c %F /var/adm
directory
```

The `-L` option works the same as for `file`, the `-c %F` option instructs `stat` to output only the type of the file, see the [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) man page for more. *BSD `stat` is not quite the same as GNU `stat`, the format strings are different, use `-f %HT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
ls -l filename
```

`man` is your friend:

```
man ls
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The output cannot tell me if the filename is linked a directory or a file. It just tell me the file-entry is a soft link.